# How to use QSqlTableModel with QTableView

Tags: python, postgresql, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

My Table view keeps coming up blank, i have tried many things so far, looked around everywhere. I have a small sample code that i am using to learn how to display a table from a PSQL database in my table view, cant seem to get it to work.

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class ProbaTabele(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(ProbaTabele,self).__init__(parent)

        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
        db.setHostName("localhost")
        db.setPort(5432)
        db.setDatabaseName("Otest")
        db.setUserName("postgres")
        db.setPassword("bizmark0")
        if (db.open() == False):
            QMessageBox.critical(None, "Database Error", db.lastError().text())
        self.db = db
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self, self.db)
        self.model.setTable("Tabela1")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.select()
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, QVariant("Name"))
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, QVariant("Salary"))
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, QVariant("Horvat"))

        self.view = QTableView(self)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    view = ProbaTabele()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: At first, Qt has examples on it, at least in C++. At second, what is "cant seem to get it to work"? At third, are SQL driver plugins loaded?

Comment: Seems pretty obvious that you need to open the database *before* trying to select the records.

Comment: The SQL driver is working, i tried putting the db.open() in my code, and it didnt help, i still got a blank table, im very new at this so its hard for me to translate C++, if somebody could point me towards a similar python example i would be very thankful

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your example. When I try it with `QSQLITE`, it all works okay. I don't know anything about postgres, but if the db opens without error, maybe you should try printing `self.model.lastError().text()` after the `select()`. Are you sure you've got the table name right?

Comment: It was a problem with the name of my table in psql, QT seems to have a bug with QSqlTableModel when you use capital letters in the table name(This bug appears only in postgresql), i changed my table name to all lower case and it worked.